# Correct directory for Tweepy API to add to the PythonPath

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, tweepy

Setup iMac 10.7.4, Eclipse Indigo, Pydev, Python 2.7

I’m trying to install the Tweepy API but the documentation is a bit sparse for any beginner programmer. I thought I had it installed as I had downloaded the necessary file to my applications folder and typed 'python setup.py install'

However I’m only now learning about the Pythonpath and the correct way of using `import`

Can anyone tell me where I should locate the Tweepy folder so that I can add it to the PythonPath

My Python "System libs" are all located in what I believe is a standard directory configuration

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/

EDIT: PythonPath Printout

```
['/Users/me/Documents/workspace/Tweeter/src',

 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg',

'/Users/me/Documents/workspace/Tweeter/src', '
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg', 

'/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.5.0.2012040618/PySrc/pydev_sitecustomize', 

'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy-1.7.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place in a folder in your PYTHONPATH.

To know which folders are in your PYTHONPATH you can run this python code

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Also sometimes you can also add packages in your current working directory.

OR put it anywhere (probably you will have to add empty file named __init__.py ) then do this before use,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/your/tweepyparentdir')
```

Comment: Hey,

When I printed out the sys.path it looks like I already have Tweepy added to the PythonPath. 

Two great recommendations though, I’m sure they will help others as well in the future.